# localization of ringed spaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

A primed ringed space is a ringed space $X$ equipped with a prime system $M$, which by definition is a map assigns to each point $x\in X$ a subset  $M_x\subseteq {\rm Spec}\, \mathcal{O}_{X,x}$.

In the work [Localization of ringed spaces](https://arxiv.org/abs/1103.2139), Gillam construct from each primed ringed spaces $(X,M)$ a natural locally ringed space $(X,M)^{loc}$ together with a morphism of ringed spaces $(X,M)^{loc}\to X$ enjoying a universal property similar to the localization of a ring at a prime ideal.

My question is the following: Given a primed ringed space $(X,M)$ with $X$ a scheme, then what condition can be imposed on the prime system $M$ so that the localization $(X, M)^{loc}$ is a scheme? Is every $M_x$ is a closed subset of ${\rm Spec}\, \mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ sufficient?

Any comment is welcome. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't think that the mentioned condition is sufficient. You will need a condition which "spreads" and does not only talk about points.

Comment: Very good question. Unfortunately I don't know the answer. I suspect that even in the case that $M$ is the terminal prime system ($M_x = \operatorname{Spec} \mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ for all $x$), where Gillam's localization coincides with Hakim's spectrum functor, the result can fail to be a scheme. But I don't really know.